# Sitting in on classes

Tags: halacha, mussar-ethics, gezel-stealing, college-university-school

Is it stealing, or in any way unethical, to sit in on lectures at university that you aren't enrolled in (therefore aren't paying fees)? A lot of people do this and it's considered normal even for lecturers to allow it, which is true of some classes I would like to attend. I can't enroll formally because I have casual work at the moment, so I don't know what days I'm free. The lecturers and the department are fine with the idea, but I believe the university does have an auditing option, which is very expensive (aimed at retirees, I think, and I can't afford it). I just wonder whether sitting in on the classes is fine, since I wouldn't enroll anyway at this time, or whether it should be considered taking something without paying for it.

How about lecture recordings, if I don't attend the class but a friend records it and I listen? Do the recordings belong to the lecturers, who would give permission, or to their employer the university, who technically would probably ask me to enroll to audit if I asked?

Don't take into account the fact that I want to go to the classes :) Just whether objectively it's acceptable.

Comment: Interesting. I've never heard of auditing fees (my university didn't have that). That makes this question much more interesting. Especially if the instructors and departments don't really care.

Comment: The "practical conscience" part seems to be asking for opinions, which is not what we deal in.

Comment: The university I attended didn't charge fees for current students or staff members but did for outsiders.  Those fees were much lower than those for taking a class for credit, but they existed.  I'd never before thought about whether informally auditing (and bypassing these fees) would be stealing from the university if the professor permits it.  Interesting question!

Comment: Hillel on the skylight, in Yoma 35?

Comment: Okay, a couple of other things... I'm not currently enrolled at the uni, though I was last year and hope to be again next year. Also, I'm not Jewish, but I listen to Jewish opinions about what is ethical.

Comment: Perhaps it isn't stealing, but (see comments on Hacham Gabriel's answer below) it might be wrong if everyone did this even despite being able to enroll. Also, if the person providing the service or owning the rights to it would probably prefer for it not to happen, is it in some way a violation of their rights of ownership? It seems to me like it should be.

Answer (score 1):

My brother told me he knows someone who asked Harav Herschel Welcher ([Posek](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1428) of Queens) about sneaking in to baseball games where tickets are sold (by non-Jews) and he replied that it would be permitted because of the general rule that זה נהנה וזה לא חסר (one party benefits while the other party loses nothing) isn't forbidden at all with non-Jews (I'm sure you'll find a lot of Torah discussion on this).

I can't see why it would be different here.

Comment: Was he mattir the chillul hashem too?

Comment: Does Ze Nehene VeZe Lo Chaser apply in a situation where if everyone did the act, no one would pay and there would be chaser?

Comment: I agree with Shmuel's question... and I am interested also about how it works if the providers of the service might prefer for it not to happen.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Similar to the [Tragedy of the Commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons). Also see the related teshuva from R' Moshe [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&hilite=261a8387-2940-4701-845e-f957ef724d0a&st=%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%9F&pgnum=222)

Comment: This could be lashon hara about this "posek"

Comment: Who knows they snuck in except themselves?

Comment: @Yehoshua, If it's an actual pesak that this prominent posek issued, then I suspect that repeating it wouldn't be lashon hara. If not, then it probably is motzi shem ra.

Comment: I take it that this opinion isn't a common one, either way?

Comment: @IsaacMoses What about the Chillul HaShem as pointed out?

Comment: @Yehoshua, If this pesak was real and addressed that aspect as well, then it seems to me that it's certainly lashon hara (among other ills) to only quote part of it. If it was a real pesak that did not address that aspect, then that's the posek's responsibility, not the repeater's, IMO. Repeating a possibly pesak on a sensitive topic through second-hand word-of-mouth could well be a bad idea in any case, since one could accidentally introduce inaccuracy.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, The Talmud's case of Ze neheneh v'ze lo chaser is sleeping in a courtyard that wouldn't otherwise be rented.  If hundreds of people slept in my courtyard, it would be damaged and thus a chisaron, right?  The fact that we don't say this suggests your line of reasoning isn't applied.

Comment: That said, I have heard the ze neheneh v'ze lo chaser idea explicitly applied to moving from a worse seat to a better one at a sporting event.